# How to get kubernetes service account access token using fabric8 java client?

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, fabric8

I have configured minikube in my local machine and going to use kubernetes externally. I have created a Service Account in kubernetes and using it's secret I can get the access token using below command.

```
kubectl get secret <service-account-secret> -o yaml -n mynamespace
```

My question is how can I do this using fabric8 java client in runtime ? What I want is to obtain the access token by giving the secret of the Service account as a parameter.

I am initiating the config as bellow.

```
Config config = new ConfigBuilder().withMasterUrl(masterURL)
                .withClientCertFile(certFile).withOauthToken(serviceAccountAccessToken).build();
```

Can I know how to get the serviceAccountAccessToken as described above using fabric8 java client ?

Answer (score 6):

The client already does that for you.

If you just create an empty Config object:

```
Config config = new ConfigBuilder().build();
```

or create the client, like:

```
KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient();
```

from within a pod, it will automatically read the token for you.

If you need to pass it elsewhere, you can just:

```
String token = config.getOauthToken();
```

or

```
String token = client.getConfiguration().getOauthToken();
```

Comment: how can we get oauthtoken from outside cluster with client?

Answer (score 1):

From within a Pod, the service account token is volume-mounted as `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` [as seen here](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/v2.6.2/kubernetes-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/Config.java#L88). The fact that the path is hard-coded in (at least v2.6.2 of) the fabric8 `Client` leads me to believe that perhaps if one merely omits the `withOauthToken()` call that the `Client` may Just Work™

It's slightly unclear whether the code snippet you provided is expected to run *outside* of the cluster, but if so then you have a small chicken-and-egg problem of providing auth to the API so you can acquire the `Secret`

Comment: Matthew, thanks for the response. I need to support this both from inside and outside of the cluster. How should I handle this then ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a service account with below yaml definition

Step 1: create api-manager.yaml with below content

kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
name: api-manager
namespace: default
rules:

- apiGroups: ["batch", "extensions"]
  resources: ["jobs","cronjob"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]

---

kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
name: udefreadonlybinding
namespace: default
subjects:

- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: api-manager
  namespace: default
  roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: job-creator
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

Step 2:
kubectl create -f api-manager.yaml

Step 3:
Edit your pod dp file and map the service account
Then map this service account to the pod which internally map the service account inside the container ( path :/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)

Step 4:  In java code
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient();
System.out.println("client"+client.getNamespace());

Answer (score 0):

```
Config config = new ConfigBuilder().withMasterUrl(externalTunnelUrl).withOauthToken(managementTokenProvider.getManagementToken(clusterName)).withUsername("management-token").build();
```

Just had the same need. OauthToken is maybe not the obvious name, but works.

Note that I do not specify client cert file there.